# Transactional API Journeys - Split decisions - Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, transactional-messaging-api

I would ask about the proper design and approach for Transactional Api Journeys with localized content. Imagine status Emails for 6 different countries. Right now it is done using a multistep Journey with an API Entry Event. Inside Journey, there is a decision split for colour or language. So the right person receives a correct status email. The downside of that solution is a slightly low delivery time and no option to set the callback with track data.

A much better solution in my mind is to use API Transactional Journeys, but each separate Journey for each case sounds painful to me.

Is there a way to create decision splits in Transactional Api Journeys in Marketing Cloud or just AMPSCRIPT on the email level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite standard case for a localization Data Extension.
Imagine you will have a data extension with following fields:

| language | color | subject | title | text | cta_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EN | Red | Thanks for purchasing our red product | Red products are the best | You will love them | See more red products |
| DA | Red | Tak fordi du købte vores røde produkt | Røde produkter er de bedste | Du vil elske dem | Se flere røde produkter |

In the transactional API payload, you should include the language and color parameters for this particular recipient. You will then use these values to lookup the correct version of the content, and use it to populate your email:

```ampscript
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @lang, @color, @i

set @lang = AttributeValue("language") 
set @color = AttributeValue("color") 

set @rows = LookupRows("Translations","language", @lang, "color", @color)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    var @subject, @title, @text, @cta_text
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
    set @subject = field(@row,"subject")
    set @title = field(@row,"title")
    set @text = field(@row,"text")
    set @cta_text = field(@row,"cta_text")

ENDIF
```

Comment: Okay, It is not exactly what I was looking for -> but it is enough as an answer. So there is no option to make decisions for Transactional API by UI, only code and ampscript, besides fact it has JounreyBuilder UI.